# ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530 Authentication required , SMTP Authentication

Tags: 7, debugging

I used [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) Module to send the email. I also added my authentication. But still got this error:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1488596457 6vQ6zwf88YaT38JwrmH9 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1488596457 6vQ6zwf88YaT38JwrmH9 " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1488596457 6vQ6zwf88YaT38JwrmH9 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 Ready to start TLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 Ready to start TLS " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 Ready to start TLS 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Ok " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com 250-8BITMIME 250-SIZE 10485760 250-STARTTLS 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250 Ok 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "530 Authentication required " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "530 Authentication required " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:530 Authentication required 
SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 530 Authentication required 
The following From address failed: sales@test.com
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? Why did I get "530" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. I used a wrong password for Authentication. I create a new ses authentication credentials in AWS and the problem solved.

Thank you.